# Develop Titanium Mobile App in Eclipse

Tags: appcelerator, titanium-mobile

For the project I am working on we need a mobile application and for a host of reasons we are going to use one of the cross-plattform frameworks. After some consideration the decision was in favor of Appcelerator / Titanium-Mobile over Phonegap.

I would like to keep to my standard development practices when developing with Titanium.

- Is there any way to develop and test titanium-mobile apps from a normal Eclipse installation? (Installing Aptana Studio is not enough)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible, but you will have to use command-line to run python script.
I don't like the way Titanium scripts are written, so I think that you should install Titanium Studio. It's not a great IDE, but it works.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. We have since decided to not use appcelerator.